# Cypress: changing the code while running crashes my tests (request aborted)

Tags: mocha.js, cypress

I'm testing an Angular App with Cypress.

I'm running my test with the Cypress dashboard, that I open using this command: 
`$(npm bin)/cypress open`

I'm calling an API with my test: **it works**.

But when I change my code, Cypress will rerun the code which will cause my first (and only my first test) to fail. **The request calling the API is aborted.**

The only way to make it work again is to manually end the process, then start it again.

Has anyone got an idea what is causing this strange behaviour?

Here is my test code:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit('/');
        cy.server();
        cy.route('POST', `myUrl`).as('apiCall');
    });

    it('should find a doctor when user searches doctor with firstName', () => {
        cy.get('#myInput').type('foo');
        cy.get('#submitButton]').click();
        cy.wait('@apiCall').then((xhr) => {
            expect(xhr.status).to.eq(200); 
        });
    });
```

Comment: Request comment aborted sounds like application bug, not the cypress

Comment: I the front I get an "error server" from the API call with no more information than that.  I have no error on the server side. weird

Comment: When request is aborted server will not see any request. I never have similar error, but I'm writing http call assertion in little bit different way. I can describe it to you, but I can not guarantee that will fix your test

Comment: Why not, let's give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare XHR stub like this:

```js
describe('', () => {
  let requests = {}; // for store sent request

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.server({ delay: 500 }); // cypress will answer for mocked xhr after 0.5s
    cy.route({
      url: '<URL>',
      method: 'POST',
      response: 'fixture:response',
      onRequest: ({ request }) => {
        Object.assign(requests, { someRequest: request.body }); // it has to be mutated
      },
    });
  });
```

And then in test:

```js
it('', () => {
  cy
    .doSomeSteps()
    .assertEqual(requests, 'someRequest', { data: 42 })
});
```

There is 2 advantages of this solution: first 0.5s delay make test more realistic because real backend doesn't answer immediately. Second is you can verify if application will send proper payload after `doSomeActions()` step.

`assertEqual` is just util to make assertion more readable

```
Cypress.Commands.add('assertEqual', (obj, key, value) =>
  cy
    .wrap(obj)
    .its(key)
    .should('deep.equal', value)
);
```

Comment: Thank for your contribution. However, stubbing the response doesn't fit my needs since I'm doing e2e test I'm interested into the server's response.

Comment: It's not about server response, it's about payload send by application to server.